# Chapter description

Tags: chapters

I would like to now how I can add a text right after a chapter.

Example: (How it is now)

> Chapter 1
>
> Introduction
>
> [Text goes here]

I would like to add a chapter description between chapter and introduction.

> Chapter 1
>
> [Here goes chapter description]
>
> Introduction
>
> [more text]

Edit documentclass includes the following:

```
%% Send any unknown option to the report class
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{report}}

\ProcessOptions\relax

\ifgfivepaper
  \LoadClass[10pt]{report}
\else
  \LoadClass[12pt]{report}
\fi

\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage[english]{babel}
\RequirePackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\sffamily\huge\bfseries} 
  {\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
```

Update: 
The following image is what I want to generate

[image]

This is how it is atm
[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Not just after ‘Introduction’, somewhat like an abstract?

Comment: Sorry about my previous comment, just understood what you mean.

Comment: so when I use \chapter{Introduction}. I get Chapter 1 followed by Introduction and then I can write text afterwards. I would like to insert (lets say an abstract) normal text between those headlines.

Comment: The answer could possibly depend on the documentclass you're using, can you add that info, or even a minimal example along the lines of `\documentclass{...} \begin{document} \chapter{Intro} Lorem ipsum. \end{document}`?

Comment: The documentclass is custom made, so dont really know what you need. But somethings that is included is:  \DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{report}}     
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}  
  \RequirePackage[english]{babel} \RequirePackage{titlesec}                                                                   \titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\sffamily\huge\bfseries}
  {\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}

Comment: Please edit your question to include that info, comments aren't the best place for code. (I don't know if I personally will be able to answer anyway, but there's a good chance someone can.)

Comment: you should clarify wht you mean with `[Here goes chapter description]` .  is this some standard text, which summarize chapter content? any text can follow chapter title, so don't understand, what is your problem. for better understanding, you should provide small, but complete document, that we can see, what you doing.

Comment: yes it should be a standard text, in which I can just write a short description of the content. But what happens when you use `\chapter{Intro}´ is that you automatically get Chapter 1 followed by Intro. I simply want to add text between those titles.

Comment: As your example chapter title is "Introduction", it looks rather like you have a *section* called "Introduction" in an unnamed chapter.  Playing with fonts ("Chapter 1" and "Introduction" the same) and spacing ("Chapter 1", intro text, and "Introduction" closer, then more of a gap before the first paragraph/section heading) could clear this up

Answer (score 1):

Solved this by adding the following before every chapter

```
{
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\sffamily\huge\bfseries}
  {\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{5pt}
  {\begin{flushleft}
  \normalfont\normalsize\textit{Here is the place where the description of each chapter goes. \vspace{0.25cm}}
  \end{flushleft}
  \Huge}
\chapter{Introduction}
}
```

Comment: A small improvement could be to add that `\titleformat` to the preamble, and put a macro in place of the description text. Then redefine that macro before each chapter, see https://gist.github.com/TorbjornT/30912a162bb5b00a473dbb4773014cfc for example. (Feel free to add this to your answer, if you like.)